# Insert Column with value (#days) between dates in other columns

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2

I have two columns; CommencementDate and ExpectedCompletionDate.  I would like to insert a column (Days) which gives the number of days between the two date columns in my table.

I'm not sure where to start.  I'm on day 5 of writing queries!

Answer (score 2):

You just have to substract ExpectedCompletionDate and CommencementDate and return the days of that.

SELECT DATEDIFF(Day, ExpectedCompletionDate, CommencementDate);

Also you can return the absolute value to ensure this is a positive value.

SELECT ABS(DATEDIFF(Day, ExpectedCompletionDate, CommencementDate));

You can see the documentation in microsft
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189794.aspx -> Datediff
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189800.aspx -> ABS